# Handling expired session in phoenix

Tags: session, phoenix-framework

I want to know how to prevent this error which I get for requesting an expired session. What could be a good way to do that? I checked [Custom Errors](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/errors.html), but not sure how helpful it is.

[image]

- First, a UUID is created and set in the session.

  ```
  uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
  SessionStore.set uuid, id, ttl: 20
  ```
- Then below URL link is sent to the user and when the user clicks, it should check if the UUID is expired in session or not.

  ```
  <% verify_url = MyAppWeb.Router.Helpers.email_url(MyAppWeb.Endpoint, :verify, uuid: @uuid) %>
  ```
- UUID is checked

  ```
  def verify(conn, %{"uuid" => uuid}) do
      user_id = SessionStore.get(uuid)
  end
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just check the nil value first. I could also use a case as suggested in [here](https://elixirforum.com/t/handling-expired-session-in-phoenix/14544).

```
if SessionStore.get(uuid) == nil do
  IO.puts "uuid expired"
else
  user_id = SessionStore.get(uuid)
  user = Accounts.get_user!(user_id)
end
```